# some time video is not playing and gives MediaPlayer error(1 , -110)

Tags: android, android-intent

i am trying to play the video from raw folder , it works but some times it gives alert dialog that "Sorry! this video can not be played",

and in logcat it shows the log path is null and gives warning.

```
09-23 13:14:17.288: W/SurfaceView(19750): CHECK surface infomation creating=false formatChanged=false sizeChanged=false visible=false visibleChanged=true surfaceChanged=true realSizeChanged=false redrawNeeded=false left=false top=false
```

Comment: The logcat line you provided looks like you simply changed the visibility of the SurfaceView (or VideoView if that's what you are using). That line is not particularly indicative of a problem. Can you explain more of what you mean by "the log path is null"?

Comment: @Dave : logcat gives error 09-23 14:54:14.070: E/MediaPlayer(28528): error (1, -110)